# How to bring the box outside of the parent div when we use 'overflow' in css

Tags: html, css

I have used CSS property 'overflow' for the parent div(#trreWrapdiv). when I click triangle (in black on zone2) down, the box with check mark should be displayed fully, but it is not.

My Aim: I should use 'overflow' for parent div. The box with check should also be displayed fully(but, it is hidden partially)

**Now**

[image]

**this should be** (I should not remove 'overlow' for parent 'div' i mean box with heading 'Devices')

[image]

css

```
#treeWrapDiv {
    border: 3px solid red;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Any help or suggestion on this please?

Comment: Can you try `overflow-x: visible;` ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay, I tried, still same state..

Comment: then providing a **JSFiddle** would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with `overflow-x: visible;` but from what I see you want this wrapper to be scrollable - you got `overflow-y: auto;` - but you cant have both scrollable box and content visible outside this box.

Solution is to place `.dropdown-menu` element outside container and position it absolutely relative to e.g. `body` with javascript.